# SQL Server: compare only month and day - SARGable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, query-performance

I have a table storing a `datetime` column, which is indexed. I'm trying to find a way to compare ONLY the month and day (ignores the year totally).

Just for the record, I would like to say that I'm already using [`MONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) and [`DAY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql). But I'm encountering the issue that my current implementation uses Index Scan instead of Index Seek, due to the column being used directly in both functions to get the month and day.

There could be 2 types of references for comparison: a fixed given date and today `(GETDATE())`. The date will be converted based on time zone, and then have its month and day extracted, e.g.

```
DECLARE @monthValue DATETIME = MONTH(@ConvertDateTimeFromServer_TimeZone);
DECLARE @dayValue DATETIME = DAY(@ConvertDateTimeFromServer_TimeZone);
```

Another point is that the column stores datetime with different years, e.g.

```
1989-06-21 00:00:00.000
1965-10-04 00:00:00.000
1958-09-15 00:00:00.000
1965-10-08 00:00:00.000
1942-01-30 00:00:00.000
```

Now here comes the problem. How do I create a SARGable query to get the rows in the table that match the given month and day regardless of the year but also not involving the column in any functions? Existing examples on the web utilise years and/or date ranges, which for my case is not helping at all.

A sample query:

```
Select t0.pk_id 
From dob t0 WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE ((MONTH(t0.date_of_birth) = @monthValue AND DAY(t0.date_of_birth) = @dayValue))
```

I've also tried `DATEDIFF()` and `DATEADD()`, but they all end up with an Index Scan.

Comment: Are you able to add a computed column to the table that stores a "normalised" date (such that it's the same as your current column but all dates are in, say, 2000)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is the only option which comes to mind, and good on you for choosing a leap year.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's not feasible to do so due to the production table's size (roughly 20 million rows) and it's also a user generated table.

Comment: Well, unfortunately `datetime` (or datetime2) is a count of intervals since some fixed date in the past. Say it's days since 1900 (for the integer portion of `datetime`). 42778 and 43143 represent the same month and day of two years but there's no way to index this data to make queries that can know that (and leap days really mess things up as well)

Comment: You could use a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) and `JOIN` on that. Ensure your Calendar has columns for Month Number and Day Number and a query containing `WHERE CT.MonthNum = @MonthValue AND CT.DayNum = @DayValue` is completely SARGable. (`CT` being Calendar Table).

Comment: A calendar table as @Larnu pointed out is probably the way forward here.

Comment: `NOLOCK` does *not* mean `don't take locks` or `go fast`. It means `read dirty data even if it's locked`

Comment: [Why you simply must have a Date Table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/).

Comment: [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) shows the dramatic performance benefits of a calendar table when processing date ranges.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the comment I made, on a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/).

This will, probably, be the easiest way to get a SARGable query. As you've discovered, `MONTH([YourColumn])` and `DATEPART(MONTH,[YourColumn])` both cause your query to become non-SARGable.

Considering that all your columns, at least in your sample data, have a time of `00:00:00` this "works" to our advantage, as they are effectively just dates. This means we can easily `JOIN` onto a Calendar Table using something like:

```
SELECT dob.[YourColumn]
FROM dob
     JOIN CalendarTable CT ON dob.DateOfBirth = CT.CalendarDate;
```

Now, if we're using the table from the above article, you will have created some extra columns (`MonthNo` and `CDay`, however, you can call them whatever you want really). You can then add those columns to your query:

```
SELECT dob.[YourColumn]
FROM dob
     JOIN CalendarTable CT ON dob.DateOfBirth = CT.CalendarDate
WHERE CT.MonthNo = @MonthValue
  AND CT.CDay = @DayValue;
```

This, as you can see, is a more SARGable query.

If you want to deal with Leap Years, you could add a little more logic using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT dob.[YourColumn]
FROM dob
     JOIN CalendarTable CT ON dob.DateOfBirth = CT.CalendarDate
WHERE CT.MonthNo = @MonthValue
  AND CASE WHEN DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) % 4 != 0 AND CT.CDat = 29 AND CT.MonthNo = 2 THEN 28 ELSE CT.Cdat END = @DayValue;
```

This treats someone's birthday on 29 February as 28 February on years that aren't leap years (when `DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) % 4 != 0`).

*It's also, probably, worth noting that it'll likely be worth while changing your DateOfBirth Column to a `date`. Date of Births aren't at a given time, only on a given date; this means that there's no implicit conversion from `datetime` to `date` on your Calendar Table.*

*Edit: Also, just noticed, why are you using `NOLOCK`? You do **know** what that does, right..? Unless you're happy with dirty reads and ghost data?*

Comment: With a Calendar table you can add an extra columns to deal with leap years, eg `LeapDay` that the same day as `Day` for each date except February 29 where it contains `28`, `IsLeapYear` to indicate leap years etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That works as well. :) The `CASE` expression was just one example, as the linked article is more an introduction to Calendar Tables.